# Draw image only on mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, drawimage

Is there any way that i could make it that "draw image" would only happen when a key/click is pressed?

I am very new to javascript but i have done html and css.

Is there a simple way that i can make this work?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color:#000000;
            image-repeat:none;
            margin: 0px;
            cursor: none;
            overflow: hidden; 
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var imageWidthHalf, imageHeightHalf;
        var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            canvas.style.display = 'block';
            document.body.appendChild( canvas );
        var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
        var image = document.createElement( 'img' );

            image.addEventListener('load', function() {
                imageWidthHalf = Math.floor( this.width / 2 );
                imageHeightHalf = Math.floor( this.height / 2 );
                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseEvent, false ); //mouseclick ?
            }   , false );

        image.src ="cir.png" 

                             //mouseclick ?
        function onMouseEvent( event ) {
            context.drawImage( image, event.clientX - imageWidthHalf , event.clientY - imageHeightHalf );
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `i have tried many things` ...what?

Comment: change `'mousemove'` to `'click'`

Comment: Have you tried `document.addEventListener( 'click', onMouseEvent, false );` instead of `document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseEvent, false );`?

Comment: I strongly recommend http://www.html5canvastutorials.com since you are new to html and javascript

Comment: Specifically starting here: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-element/

Comment: Thanks guys :) and thanks for the site recommendation

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add jQuery to your project, it makes life quite easier.

```
  $("canvas").click(function() {
     // alert("Handler for .click() called.");
      context.drawImage( image, event.clientX - imageWidthHalf , event.clientY - imageHeightHalf );
  });
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: also try a canvas framework which makes drawing easy. Consider: http://kineticjs.com